# Is it normal for a SMPS mains smoothing cap to still hold a charge after many many hours

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I have a PSU with 2 200V 330μF main smoothing caps.

I noticed that > 6 hours after having shut down the PSU there was still 0.6v that could be measured on one of the main filter caps.

Would that be considered normal , or should I expect this to have been gone to 0v (or a couple of microvolts)

I do have to say that the PSU is currently not working (not outputting any DC voltages) and that it was turned on for about 1 minute to do some diagnostics.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about 600 mV. Typically, there should be a "bleeder" resistor that should be able to bring it down to zero. But 600 mV wouldn't bother me unless something else in the circuit also worried me about it. Lacking that, I'd say "don't worry."

Comment: Large value electrolytic caps can "hide" charge in chemical reactions within the cap, and spontaneously recharge themselves when the chemical reactions are reversed. If the cap was connected to a150V or 200V DC source for several hours, discharged to measure zero volts, and then disconnected completely from the circuit, it might measure 10 volts or more an hour after you disconnected it.

Comment: @alephzero ...and way more than 10V in your scenario for a capacitor slightly gone bad.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it normal for a SMPS mains smoothing cap to still hold a charge after many many hours

yes.

> I noticed that > 6 hours after having shut down the PSU there was still 0.6v that could be measured on one of the main filter caps.

That really sounds benign and to be expected.